# React lose focus of select after click

Tags: reactjs

I am using react antd component library and I am having trouble losing focus of the select after I select an item in the dropdown. I am thinking it needs to call a blur method so it loses focus but Im not sure.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd4103-forked-81i3d

Steps to reproduce,

click the dropdown and select a name item in the dropdown. Then when the dropdown closes, click it again. The dropdown should show but it doesnt. The user needs to select outside of the dropdown then click it again. I need to make it so they can click the selet at any point and it shows the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't need to use `open` and also, you have some additional error

```
dropdownRender={menu => (
          <div>
             {menu}
           </dive>}
```

the empty tag is frustrating to see, and it is not a good manner.

This is the complete code code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select, Button } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = React.useState(false);

  function onChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    setDropdown(false);
  }

  function onBlur() {
    console.log("blur");
    setDropdown(false);
  }

  function onFocus() {
    console.log("focus");
    setDropdown(true);
  }

  function onSearch(val) {
    console.log("search:", val);
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setDropdown(!dropdown);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        showSearch
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Select a person"
        optionFilterProp="children"
        onChange={onChange}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onSearch={onSearch}
        filterOption={(input, option) =>
          option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
        open={dropdown}
        onDropdownVisibleChange={handleClick}
        dropdownRender={(menu) => (
          <div>
            {menu}
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>Close</Button>
          </div>
        )}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SelectSizesDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[Runnable version](https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd4103-forked-v4v7z?file=/index.js)

Comment: I didnt include it in the example but instead of the close button,I have a link to another page. When I click the button the navbar should close. In the example you gave the navbar doesnt close when clicking the button

Comment: The dropdown should close when clicking the close button

Comment: You need to change your variable when the component when you click on the item instead of the Button, in other words, you need to use `onDropdownVisibleChange={handleClick}`. I update the code

Comment: One more thing, the handleClick gets called when the select is clicked not just the close button. Is there any way to only call it when the close btn is clicked or determine if it was called from the btn?

Comment: the onDropdownVisibleChange need to change your local variable because you component can be close not only from the button. but I think yes, you can add a parameter method in the function